# PDFLaTeX starts every time I type in math environments

Tags: math-mode, editors, preview, sublime-text, miktex2.9

Every time I want to type in math environments the `MikTeX (2.9)` pdflatex.exe starts in a separate console window and stands for a while until it closes and some other consoles appear and disappear very quickly.

A few minutes ago I tried to fix the problem with the phantom preview in math environment. I installed ImageMagic with the legacy option but it did not help.

Now I can't even type when math preview is disabled. I'm going crazy. I can't do my homework at the moment.

Please help. Thank you.

**[Edit]**

I use `Sublime Text 3`. When I am in any math mode and I type or delete a character this window appears. [image: pdflatex.exe] After a while it disappears and several other windows like the one before appear and disappear very fast.

Which information I can provide more?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please add which editor you are using and a more precise problem description.

Comment: I edited my text

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. I had a Problem with the Latex Equation Preview package. I removed it and the annoying window does not appear anymore.